# get all retweets user-id for each tweet-id

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I have a list of tweets Id more than 100 and I want to get all retweets Id for each tweet Id the code that I used is for one tweet Id how can I give the list of tweets Id and check if there is retweets for this tweet print the user ids

```
# import the module 

import tweepy 

  
# assign the values accordingly 

consumer_key = "" 

consumer_secret = "" 

access_token = "" 

access_token_secret = "" 

  
# authorization of consumer key and consumer secret 

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret) 

  
# set access to user's access key and access secret  
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret) 

  
# calling the api  

api = tweepy.API(auth) 

  
# the ID of the tweet 

ID = 1265889240300257280

  
# getting the retweeters 

retweets_list = api.retweets(ID) 

  
# printing the screen names of the retweeters 

for retweet in retweets_list: 

    print(retweet.user.screen_name)
```

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

For getting Retweets from a list of Tweets, you'll need to iterate over your list of Tweet IDs and call the `api.retweets` function for each one in turn.

---

If your Tweets themselves have more than 100 Retweets, you'll hit a limitation in the API.

Per the Tweepy [documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.9.0/api.html#API.retweets):

> API.retweets(id[, count])
>
> > Returns up to 100 of the first retweets of the given tweet.

The Twitter API itself only supports retrieving up to 100 Retweets, see the [API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-retweets-id) (this is the same API that Tweepy is calling):

> GET statuses/retweets/:id
>
> > Returns a collection of the 100 most recent retweets of the Tweet specified by the id parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
for retweet in retweets_list: 

    print (retweets_list.retweet_count)
```